# Which DD-WRT Version do I choose?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, firmware

There are a few versions of firmware avaliable for my router TP-Link Archer C7 AC1750 e.g. 1.x 2.x 3.x and 4.x
[Here](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/)

I am not sure which one I should choose. I'm new to flashing routers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for any specific enhancements, features, security, or are you just doing this "because updates"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a beta version that seems to be stable and has good performance. Link [here](https://dd-wrt.com/support/other-downloads/?path=betas%2F2019%2F05-15-2019-r39800%2Ftplink_archer-c7-v5%2F)

Answer (score 0):

You should choose according to the revision number of the router. Same models have different hardware. If you choose the wrong one you may brick it.

Comment: So where it says "Hardware Version Archer C7 v5.0" I would select version 5.x in ddwrt or the "Firmware version 1.0.4" and select 1.x"?